# UBUNTU 18.04 freezes without any suspicious activity

Tags: 18.04, kernel, freeze

I had just installed ubuntu 18.04 and updated the kernel to 4.19 .11 , it freezes from time to time and I have tried that with other kernel versions too , also installed ubuntu couple of times but still it keeps on freezing such that I have to force shutdown using power button . I tried to track that using system monitor or log files but not to much avail .Could someone help me with it?

here is the /var/log/boot.log

```
 [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
         Starting WPA supplicant...
         Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting Network Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting Disk Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started irqbalance daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Run anacron jobs.
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
         Starting Bluetooth service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting Snappy daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Bluetooth service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Bluetooth.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
         Starting Hostname Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Hostname Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started WPA supplicant.`
```

Comment: Is there something in the boot log you want us to see? If so, what?

Comment: @karel I had tried all of the suggestions in the answer , none of  them worked to force shutdown the system

Comment: @user535733 I just posted it that if it leaves a trail that I'm not able to find.

Comment: Random freezing could be bad RAM (look up how to run MEMTEST) or an incompatible video card, or several other causes. Most leave clues in /var/log/syslog.